# Where can I find the neo4j 2.2 JDBC driver binaries?

Tags: jdbc, neo4j

We are currently using the 2.0.0-M06 snapshot version of the neo4j jdbc driver and are trying to use the latest version available.  We found the 2.1.4 version on the maven repository below,
https://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-jdbc/

However, while trying to use this we see the below error..

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error during parsing
 at    org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.StreamingParser$ParserState.nextToken(StreamingParser.java:71)
at org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.StreamingParser.skipTo(StreamingParser.java:313)
at org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.StreamingParser.nextResult(StreamingParser.java:130)
at org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.StreamingParser$2.hasNext(StreamingParser.java:265)
at org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.StreamingParser$2$1.endReached(StreamingParser.java:269)
at org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.StreamingParser$1.hasNext(StreamingParser.java:201)
at org.neo4j.jdbc.IteratorResultSet.hasNext(IteratorResultSet.java:98)
at org.neo4j.jdbc.IteratorResultSet.next(IteratorResultSet.java:63)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.next(NewProxyResultSet.java:2859)
... 92 more
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.ensureOpen(StreamDecoder.java:46)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:148)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at  org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser.loadMore(ReaderBasedParser.java:117)
at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser._skipWSOrEnd(ReaderBasedParser.java:1476)
at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedParser.java:368)
at org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.StreamingParser$ParserState.nextToken(StreamingParser.java:67)
... 100 more
```

We found a reference that this is addressed in the 2.2 version of the driver and are therefore trying to download that. Can someone please point us in the right direction in getting this 2.2 binary for the neo4j-jdbc driver? Also, we currently use the neo4j 2.2 version for our db server.
Thx,
NN

Answer (score 0):

I think version 2.2 is not released yet.

You can try to build your own binaries from the source code - https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc